# How do I turn on designMode in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I placed this inside index.html

```
<script>
document.designMode = "on";
</script>
```

But it didn't make any of the React components editable.

Comment: It makes the html elements editable, not react components

Comment: Thank you.  That saved me some headaches I turned contenteditable for the body and got the desired effect.